# Difference between activate and viewAttached in Durandal?

Tags: durandal

What is the difference between the two, and when is it appropriate to use each?  I've seen the documentation but haven't quite been able to work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both events are part of the Durandal Lifecyle callbacks.

`activate()` Allows the new object to execute custom activation logic. (View Model)

`viewAttached()` Notifies the new object when its view is attached to its parent DOM node. (Composition).

See http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/ for in depth comparision.

**Update based on comment**
In Durandal 2.x `viewAttached()` has become `attached()`. Also the documentation is now here http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

Comment: I think of activate as a place where I can load data that needs to be first displayed when the view is loaded where as ViewAttached as the place to call jquery code. If this makes it easy.

Comment: I read this, and the light bulb went on.  Still new to Durandal... Thanks both of you.

Comment: In Durandal 2.x `viewAttached()` has become `attached()`. Also the documentation is now here http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

Answer (score 2):

Rainer is correct, but to expand on that.

`activate` is a method that is called *before* data-binding occurs, to ensure the viewmodel is in a stable state and can be safely data-bound to.

`viewAttached` is a callback to notify that data-binding has *completed*, and the DOM can safely be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of durandal doesn't have a `viewAttached` callback, it is simply `attached` now.

[Durandal Lifecycle callbacks](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html)